# AWS Cognito -- Email is Required by default, but the default sign up form doesn't have an email field

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-three/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-two) and I'm stuck at the point of adding auth using aws cognito. I ran `amplify add auth` and accepted all the dafaults. I then ran `amplify push --y`.

Now, when I run the app, my sign up screen has only 3 fields: Username, Password, and Confirm Password. There's nowhere to enter the email. However, when I click "Create Account" I get the error `Attributes did not conform to the schema: email: The attribute is required`.

How do I make there be an email field, or otherwise resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you still stuck here?

Comment: @AnkushJain yeah I am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are still having this issue, then can you please try `Authenticator` component directly instead of `withAuthenticator` as shown here [Step 3. Add the Authenticator](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator).

Also, I just added `email` in signupAttributes attribute. Refer [this](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/configuration#sign-up-attributes) for more detail.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator signUpAttributes={['email']}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```