# How to add email field to Amplify authentication?

Tags: aws-amplify

I am new to development. I am following this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-three/

I successfully completed all of the steps in module 3 prior to "Run the app locally." When I run the app locally using `npm start` I see all fields except for email:

[image]

I'd appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: Check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647856/aws-cognito-email-is-required-by-default-but-the-default-sign-up-form-doesn

Comment: Bhavesh, this is helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I was also facing the same problem today. All you need to do is to import the Authenticator component directly here is the code format below.

```js
import React from "react";

import "@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css";
import {
  Authenticator,
  Button
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator signUpAttributes={['email']}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</Button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

Comment: MeetMuaz, thank you! This solved my problem.